# "The name 'HighScoreList' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, arrays, leaderboard

So I'm trying to pull playername and count from a file, and save them into a variable for high scores..

I dont understand why this error is happening though. At all.
I've also tried to ask on the unity forums but this hasn't helped much.

Code:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using System;

public class highscores : MonoBehaviour {

 public int[] HighScoreList;
 public string[] HighScoreListNames;
 public int score;
 public Text HighScore0;
 public Text HighScore1;
 public Text HighScore2;
 public Text HighScore3;
 public Text HighScore4;

 void Awake()
 {
     HighScoreList = new int [5];
     HighScoreList [0] = 0;
     HighScoreList [1] = 0;
     HighScoreList [2] = 0;
     HighScoreList [3] = 0;
     HighScoreList [4] = 0;
     HighScoreListNames = new string [5];
     HighScoreListNames [0] = "";
     HighScoreListNames [1] = "";
     HighScoreListNames [2] = "";
     HighScoreListNames [3] = "";
     HighScoreListNames [4] = "";
 }

 void GetScore () 
 {
     string[] currentscore = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (@"C:\Users\Plum\Desktop\Pixel Ninjav3.3\Assets\leaderboard.txt");
     score = Convert.ToInt32(currentscore[1]);
     if (score >= HighScoreList[0])
     {
         HighscoreList[4] = HighScoreList[3];
         HighscoreList[3] = HighScoreList[2];
         HighscoreList[2] = HighScoreList[1];
         HighscoreList[1] = HighScoreList[0];
         HighscoreList[0] = score;
         HighScoreListNames[4] = HighScoreListNames[3];
         HighScoreListNames[3] = HighScoreListNames[2];
         HighScoreListNames[2] = HighScoreListNames[1];
         HighScoreListNames[1] = HighScoreListNames[0];
         HighScoreListNames[0] = currentscore[0];
     }
     else if (score >= HighScoreList[1])
     {
         HighscoreList[4] = HighScoreList[3];
         HighscoreList[3] = HighScoreList[2];
         HighscoreList[2] = HighScoreList[1];
         HighscoreList[1] = score;
         HighScoreListNames[4] = HighScoreListNames[3];
         HighScoreListNames[3] = HighScoreListNames[2];
         HighScoreListNames[2] = HighScoreListNames[1];
         HighScoreListNames[1] = currentscore[0];
     }
     else if (score >= HighScoreList[2])
     {
         HighscoreList[4] = HighScoreList[3];
         HighscoreList[3] = HighScoreList[2];
         HighscoreList[2] = score;
         HighScoreListNames[4] = HighScoreListNames[3];
         HighScoreListNames[3] = HighScoreListNames[2];
         HighScoreListNames[2] = currentscore[0];
     }
     else if (score >= HighScoreList[3])
     {
         HighscoreList[4] = HighScoreList[3];
         HighscoreList[3] = score;
         HighScoreListNames[4] = HighScoreListNames[3];
         HighScoreListNames[3] = currentscore[0];
     }
     else if (score >= HighScoreList[4])
     {
         HighscoreList[4] = score;
         HighScoreListNames [4] = currentscore[0];
     }

 }
}
```

Comment: @DanielLawton, have you used the debugger to determine which line it's failing on exactly.. ?

Comment: @GrantWinney All the lines beneath the ifs and else ifs to do with the HighScoreList array

Comment: @MethodMan It's failing on all lines with HighScoreList[4] = HighScoreList [3] etc under the if and else if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. Meaning you cant mix "HighScoreList" and "HighscoreList".

You only declared HighScoreList. With Score capitalized. But in your ifs you also use HighscoreList with score in lower case.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks for pointing that out :)